# Connection Request is 400 Bad Request with Codename one

Tags: codenameone

We have a many customers that used our application (HR) we are build it using codenameone and everything is working probably, but today we received a problem from one customer there is a message appear contain **400 Bad request** and other customers are working without any problem.

this line is given the 400 bad request
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(req)

we checked the Network monitor and checked the URL that return the json without any problem.

If you have any idea or possibilities to help us to can fix this problem

Comment: Great to hear that, is the app submitted to the gallery?

Comment: Yes, In google play and App store, VOLT HRMS, but you should put the customer server link to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the error by overriding the error messages in the connection request or network manager.

Generally a 400 error happens when you make an invalid request to the server although it can also be a temporary error. I suggest adding `Log.p(String)` and `Log.e(err)` calls and print out logs/request data then using `Log.sendLog()` when an error occurs. This will allow you to track production errors like this.

Comment: I will test your recommended and back to you